# C# portable IDE and compiler - all it requires needs to be on an USB flash drive

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, ide

it exist a fully portable compiler and IDE for C#? All the things I need to code a C# application needs to be on an USB flash drive (even the .NET framework). So, what I need is a fully integrated programming tool, to insert the flash drive and to be ready to code.

It exist something like this?

LE: I can do this by using a virtual machine. I'm asking if I can do this without it. So, all what I need to be on the USB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a VM setup just the way you want it and put the image on a USB key.

There are many free and portable [virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) you can use for this.

Update:

Since your question is now specifically about doing without a VM - the answer is no. You can't install the .NET framework on USB.

You *can* install an IDE like SharpDevelop or MonoDevelop on a key and possibly the Mono compiler, but not the framework as supplied by Microsoft.

See [this](http://portableapps.com/node/1604) for getting a full portable mono environment.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing :)

Comment: I know I can do this. I was asking it I can do this without a VM.

Comment: @RBA - Were you? You didn't mention VMs in your question at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can also Google for "portable SharpDevelop". SharpDevelop is a free, open-source full featured C# IDE, with compiler, window designer, intellisense and a lot of bells and whistles.

Comment: @RBA - As far as I know, that (installing the .NET framework on a USB key) is not possible.

Comment: That's trickier. I don't think the several portable SharpDevelop packages I've seen listed on Google are TRULY portable (can't investigate further, as I'm at work and my corporate proxy is quite restrictive). You need to have the .NET framework installed in the target machine for the IDE to run, since it's made with .NET. Since Windows 7 (or it was Vista?), it comes included with Windows, so no problem. Previous versions, you should have the .NET redistributable (free and not too big for modern USB units, I think) included on your USB and install it previous to use the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The C# compilers is installed wherever a .NET Framework is. Since the .NET Framework is NOT optional in any recent Windows OS, I would say that you only need to worry about the portable IDE, and for that you might want to use, as Picacodigos suggested, SharpDevelop:

Have a look here: http://laputa.sharpdevelop.net/SharpDevelopOnAMemoryStick.aspx